# If $f$ is locally integrable function $\implies \int_I f(t)\,dt$ converges

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

> How to prove :
>
> If $f$ is locally integrable function , bounded over an bounded interval (closed, half closed, or open) then $\displaystyle \int_If(t)\,dt$ converges.

I have got a proof which is a little difficult, it uses different theorems.

I would like to know if my proof, which seems to be mush easier,  is correct?

---

Let $I =(a,b)$

As $f$ is bounded $\inf(f)$ and $\sup(f)$ exist

$\displaystyle \underset{(a,b)}{\inf (f)}(b-a)\le\int_a^bf(t)\,dt\le \underset{(a,b)}{\sup (f)}(b-a)$ then $$\displaystyle \left|\int_a^bf(t)\,dt\right|\le \max\left(\left|\underset{(a,b)}{\inf (f)}(b-a)\right|,\;\left|\underset{(a,b)}{\sup (f)}(b-a)\right| \right)=A$$
Then it follows $\displaystyle \int_If(t)\,dt$ converges $\Box$